# Not being able to set state for a selected date from a DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, state, onchange

So I am having trouble with setting the state for the date selected from this DatePicker

change:

```
  change = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
```

DatePicker component:

```
<DatePicker
      selected={this.state.startDate}
      onChange={e => this.change(e)}
 />
```

If I use the default date when you first reload the page, there is no issue. But it's when a date is selected that I get an error.

> A Type Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your state have any value like e.target.name? Try rereading react docs.

Answer (score 0):

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

More information can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling).

---

Since `setState` is asynchronous the `event` will be `null` by the time it's evaluated in `setState`.

Instead, deconstruct the `event` before `setState`:

```
change = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
  this.setState({
    [name]: value,
  });
}
```

or

```
change = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState({
    [name]: value,
  });
}
```